# How to update React state with if else condition in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component I want to update parent state from child component clicked. But there is if else condition due to this I'm not able to update state in parent component.

I have two boxes with if else condition & I want to update state in both boxes but its update in only one box. How to solve this?

[Working sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-issue-with-if-else-condition-rmi7k1?file=/src/styles.css)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**App.js code:**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Halfbox from "./Halfbox";

export default function App(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(false);
  if (props.type == "left-section") {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <b class="state"> {name ? <>right update</> : <>right not update</>}</b>
        <Halfbox setName={setName} />
      </div>
    );
  } else if (props.type == "right-section") {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <b class="state"> {name ? <>left update</> : <>left not update</>}</b>
        <p>This is left box</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Halfbox.js code:**

```js
export default function Halfbox(props) {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    props.setName(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Halfbox</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `if (props.type == "left-section")` - Where is this prop coming from?  Do you have other components wrapping `<App>`?  What is causing that prop to change?  *In the code shown*, under what condition would this prop ever change?  If you're only conditionally rendering `<App>` then removing and re-adding it could reset its state, depending on how you're doing that.

Comment: It seems that there are 2 instance of `App`, therefore each has its own `name` state. And the event is only updating the state for its parent `App` but not the other one.

Comment: if (props.type == "left-section") this is coming from index.js

Comment: @John Li there is any other way?, basically i need to update state in both of the boxes.

Comment: @RohitVerma: *"this is coming from index.js"* - Then it's part of a [mcve] and should be included in the question.  Currently the entire "problem" appears to be that you have **two** instances of `<App>`.  So you have two different state values.  There's no reason updating one should affect the other.  You are encouraged to look into "lifting state up" and/or using a global state management system, such as `useContext` or Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are 2 instance of `App`, therefore each has its own `name` state. And the event is only updating the state for its parent `App` but not the other one.

To have both boxes updated, perhaps a very basic approach could be try moving them down as child components of the same `App`, so that they can share the `name` state passed down from it.

Example: (forked live on: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-issue-with-if-else-condition-forked-f813u8?file=/src/App.js))

```
export default function App(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Section
        type="left-section"
        title="Left Section"
        name={name}
        setName={setName}
      />
      <Section
        type="right-section"
        title="Right Section"
        name={name}
        setName={setName}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
export const Section = (props) => {
  if (props.type === "left-section") {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <b className="state">
          {props.name ? <>right update</> : <>right not update</>}
        </b>
        <Halfbox setName={props.setName} />
      </div>
    );
  } else if (props.type === "right-section") {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <b className="state">
          {props.name ? <>left update</> : <>left not update</>}
        </b>
        <p>This is left box</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for share differ approach.